# Echart Bar Graph Reverse Yaxis

Tags: javascript, graph, reverse, axis-labels, echarts

I am trying to create a bar graph use Echarts. I am trying to reverse the YAxis. The data that I am trying to display considers a lower time as a higher score and a higher time as a lower score. Currently, the graph display as the higher time has a higher score. I am having trouble trying to reverse the YAxis. Any help would be great.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dom = document.getElementById("chartPace");
  var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
  app.title = 'Test';

option = { 
color: ["#000000"],
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: false,

grid : {
      height: '250',
      width: '450'
  },
  title : {
      text: 'test'
  },
  xAxis : [
      {
          type : 'category',
          data : ['Mon','Tue','Wensday','Tue','Wensday'],
          axisTick: {
              alignWithLabel: true
          }, 
      }
  ],
  yAxis : [
      {
          type : 'time',
          reversed:true,
          axisLabel: {
          formatter: function (value) {
            var value = new Date(value);
            var minutes = value.getMinutes();
            if (value.getSeconds().toString().length < 2){
              var seconds =  "0" + value.getSeconds();
            }
            else{
              var seconds = value.getSeconds();
            }
            return minutes +":" + seconds;
            //return value;
          }
        }
      }
  ],
  tooltip:{
    formatter : function (params) {

      var value = new Date(params['data']);
            var minutes = value.getMinutes();
            if (value.getSeconds().toString().length < 2){
              var seconds =  "0" + value.getSeconds();
            }
            else{
              var seconds = value.getSeconds();
            }
              return minutes +":" + seconds;
    }
  },
  series : [
      {
          name:'Avg Pace',
          type:'bar',
          barWidth: '60%',
          data:[new Date(2014, 9, 1, 0, 2,30),
          new Date(2014, 9, 1, 0, 1,05),
          new Date(2014, 9, 1, 0, 2,30),
          new Date(2014, 9, 1, 0, 3,20),
          new Date(2014, 9, 1, 0, 1,25),
          new Date(2014, 9, 1, 0, 0,00)]
      }
  ]
  };

  if (option && typeof option === "object") {
  myChart.setOption(option, true);
  }
  $(window).on('resize', function(){
      if(chart != null && chart != undefined){
          chart.resize();
      }
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: You mistyped `reversed: true` in yAxis. It should be `inverse: true`. Docs: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#yAxis

Comment: Is there a way to inverse the xaxis but keep the graph start from the bottom up?

Comment: I guess you would need to use `xAxis.position: 'top'`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `inverse:true` in Y-axis.